# Maximum digits in Base10 ASCII Representation of UTC Time in android

Tags: android, utc

A **4 byte** Long integer can give

> (2^(32) - 1) = 4294967295

**10 digit**

Now, the time given by *Location Manager* in *android* is **currently 13 digit** long( like 1366588814000 ).
Can the number of digits increase in future as time progresses ? I don't know in what **data type** android stores the time.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the getTime() is long as mentioned in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29). So you need not worry about the length of the digits. You can always convert that time to a human readable form like

```
long time = location.getTime();
Date date = new Date(time);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String text = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: By doing so I can convert it into a 'more' readable and 'finite-no-of-digits' format. Thanks! But I still seek answer to my question. Can we predict the number of digits in ASCII representation to the time(Unix Time Format)?